# Hibernate criteria order by one-to-many association count

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity "X" with a one-to-many association to "Y"s

Each X has a unique xid, and each Y has an xid, and a unique yid

I want to write a criteria that produces a list of X's ordered by the number of associated Y's

Here is the equivalent SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM X JOIN Y ON X.xid = Y.xid
GROUP BY X.xid
ORDER BY COUNT(Y.yid) DESC
```

How do I express this using Hibernate Criteria?

Many thanks
Peter

Comment: Do you mean JPA CriteriaQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to create an `alias` for the Y collection, get its count, and sort by it. Here is an example:

```
// Create the criteria assuming session is open
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(X.class, "x");

// Give the Y association an alias
criteria.createAlias("x.yCollectionName", "yCollectionAlias"); 

// Get the count of IDs in the joined collection
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("yCollectionAlias.id"))
.add(Projections.count("yCollectionAlias.id").as("yCollectionAliasCount")));

// Sort the criteria associated by Ys
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("yCollectionAliasCount"));
```

Comment: Actually, this does not for me.  When I try the above code, instead of getting a list of X entities, I get a list of Object arrays with elements yCollectionAlias.id and yCollectionAliasCount.  I just want a list of X's sorted by yCollectionAliasCount.  How do I do that?

Comment: Would you mind posting more of your code so I can see what you are doing?

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, can you please un-check it as the selected answer? I started trying to implement this before reading your comment that says it doesn't work.

Comment: The best solution I've found for this question is using a custom `Order` class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254306/hibernate-criteria-api-how-to-order-by-collection-size or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855253/hibernate-criteria-order-by-count-of-child-records