# Hibernate Criteria order by count of child records

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes: News and Comments with one-to-many association between them.
I am using Hibernate Criteria to fetch news from database. I would like my news to be ordered by the count of its comments.

```
session.createCriteria(News.class, "n");
criteria.createAlias("n.comments", "comments");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("comments.id"))
    .add(Projections.count("comments.id").as("numberOfComments")));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("numberOfComments"));
List<News> news = criteria.list();
```

With the following code I'm getting not the list of news but the list of objects with two Long's in each of them.
What should I do to get the list of sorted news objects?

Comment: I would probably try using Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("n.comments", "comments") instead of createAlias(). Then using the setProjection only on subCriteria.

Comment: @Matej, those changes result in fetching the same list of unknown objects as I had.

Comment: Another blind shot - have a look to Hibernate's documentation how they are using .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP) and then getting the main object using map.get(Criteria.ROOT_ALIAS) while iterating the list. This might help.

Comment: @Matej, I've tried that like in the following tutorial.
http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/06/result-transformers.html
But there is a problem. We do not have the news alias after we applied the projections. The root alias is "numberOfComments" now. And I get the list of comments count for each of news, but even without the id of that news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question here:
[Hibernate Criteria API - how to order by collection size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254306/hibernate-criteria-api-how-to-order-by-collection-size)

I've added the new hibernate Order implementation:

```
public class SizeOrder extends Order {

protected String propertyName;
protected boolean ascending;

protected SizeOrder(String propertyName, boolean ascending) {
    super(propertyName, ascending);
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
    this.ascending = ascending;
}

public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
    String role = criteriaQuery.getEntityName(criteria, propertyName) + '.' + criteriaQuery.getPropertyName(propertyName);
    QueryableCollection cp = (QueryableCollection) criteriaQuery.getFactory().getCollectionPersister(role);

    String[] fk = cp.getKeyColumnNames();
    String[] pk = ((Loadable) cp.getOwnerEntityPersister())
            .getIdentifierColumnNames();
    return " (select count(*) from " + cp.getTableName() + " where "
            + new ConditionFragment()
                    .setTableAlias(
                            criteriaQuery.getSQLAlias(criteria, propertyName)
                    ).setCondition(pk, fk)
                .toFragmentString() + ") "
            + (ascending ? "asc" : "desc");
}

public static SizeOrder asc(String propertyName) {
    return new SizeOrder(propertyName, true);
}
public static SizeOrder desc(String propertyName) {
    return new SizeOrder(propertyName, false);
}
}
```

And then applied that to my criteria as

`criteria.addOrder(SizeOrder.desc("n.comments"));`

Now everything works fine,
thanks everyone a lot :)